# Connecting with WebClient to a proxy that has authentication required

Tags: c#, proxy

i am trying to connect to a private proxy which requires authentication (user:pass)
and the IP.

Trying to test if the proxy is working here is my code , and i always end up in the catch :

```
    public static bool IsUp(string proxy, int timeout, string url = "https://www.youtube.com/")
    {
        bool isUp = true;
        WebProxy webProxy;
        //remove ssl warning
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        if (proxy.Count(x => x == ':') >= 2)
        {
            string proxyUser = proxy.Split(new char[] { ':', ':' })[2];
            string proxyPass = proxy.Split(new char[] { ':', ' ' })[3];
            string proxyProxy = proxy.Split(new char[] { ' ', ':' })[0] + ':' + proxy.Split(new char[] { ':', ':' })[1];
            ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUser, proxyPass);
            webProxy = new WebProxy(proxyProxy,true,null,credentials);
        }
        else
            webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        WebClient client = new Utilities.TimeoutWebClient(timeout);
        client.Proxy = webProxy;

        try
        {
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
        }
        catch(Exception lol)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lol.Message);
            isUp = false;
        }

        return isUp;
    }
```

The exception is : 
the underlying connection was closed : an unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Is it because i need to make the stream do something? Even though it openread the url 
Still not working

Comment: So what is the exception?

Comment: @BenRobinson My bad forgot to add it 
here it is :
the underlying connection was closed : an unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: have you stepped into the code that creates the `WebProxy` instance? Is it instantiated correctly with the provided credentials?